# Is there any difference between messages in soapbinding style: document vs RPC?

Tags: web-services

Is there any difference between  messages in soapbinding style: document vs RPC?

I understand that document style populated xsd with details of in/out - request/response messages in document style and not in RPC making it easier for developer on client side to understand what message shall finally leave client/server.

Comment: What do you mean, "any differences". Of _course_ there are differences, or the two wouldn't have different names! What are you asking?

Comment: What is the difference in "in/out messages"(soap head/body xml,tags) sent when RPC is used vs document?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are many differences. The SOAP came came into picture before the XSD existed. Read  this [SOAP Binding: Difference between Document and RPC Style Web Services](http://java.globinch.com/enterprise-java/web-services/soap-binding-document-rpc-style-web-services-difference/) to know more about this